# Difference between as_json and to_json method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the difference between the two methods `as_json` and `to_json`. Are they same? If not what's the difference between them?

Comment: See [this](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`to_json` returns String. 
`as_json` returns Hash with String keys.

```
> { :name => "Konata Izumi", 'age' => 16, 1 => 2 }.to_json
"{\"name\":\"Konata Izumi\",\"age\":16,\"1\":2}"

> { :name => "Konata Izumi", 'age' => 16, 1 => 2 }.as_json
{"name"=>"Konata Izumi", "age"=>16, "1"=>2}
```

Comment: If wondering which to use in a controller rendering json, "In controllers, do not call to_json directly, allow render to do that for you. If you need to tweak the JSON output, override as_json in your model, or call as_json directly." - from [here](https://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/).

Answer (score 67):

`as_json` returns a hash representation of your model object, while `to_json` returns a json object.

Note: Internally, when you call the `to_json` method on your model/serializer, as_json is first called.

You can [read more here](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/)