# How can I access Rails variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails variable that I need to pull all the dates and time (send_time) and put into a JS array. I am trying to use the JS array of sent_times to block users from using those date/times in the future. Think scheduling a meeting room for one hour blocks. Two meetings can't go at the same time.

I have inspected the variable in my JS.

```
var taken = <%= @taken.inspect.html_safe %>;
```

Here is the inspected variable

```
    var taken = [

    #<ScheduledRequest _id: 5b7f6b2842195a000400000f, send_time: 2018-08-25 18:00:00 UTC, sent_time: nil, warning_time: 2018-08-25 16:30:00 UTC, actual_send_time: 2018-08-25 16:45:00 UTC, processing: nil, retries: 10, pickup_address: "2209 West Anderson Lane, Boston, MA, USA", dropoff_address: "2209 West Anderson Lane, Boston, MA, USA", round_trip: false, token: nil, pickup_location: [-37.729439, 40.355348], dropoff_location: [-47.729439, 30.355348], notes: "Scheduled: Simple assembly and take away trash.", ip: "XHgw1nn3xIHzfs5t2xzZ/ez0Tj5gg=", notify_email: "", notify_phone: "", user_id: "53f4b008", thingy_type: "Blue Row", thingy_request_id: nil, error: nil, two_hour_warning_sent: nil, identifier: nil, estimated_time: "", thingy_request_log: nil, for_customer_api: false, removed: false, edit_date: "2018-08-25", edit_hours: "01", edit_minutes: "00", edit_ampm: "PM">, 

    #<ScheduledRequest _id: 5b7f92964029e90004000013, send_time: 2018-08-28 01:00:00 UTC, sent_time: nil, warning_time: 2018-08-27 23:30:00 UTC, actual_send_time: 2018-08-27 23:45:00 UTC, processing: nil, retries: 10, pickup_address: "5501 Spicewood Springs Road, Boston, MA, USA", dropoff_address: "2345 West Anderson Lane, Boston, MA, USA", round_trip: false, token: nil, pickup_location: [-77.771753, 20.384814], dropoff_location: [-57.7322452, 10.356484], notes: "Scheduled:", ip: "XHgwMmB7fk1lRn1Bg8ooqhwM4xQsg=", notify_email: "", notify_phone: "", user_id: "53f4b08", thingy_type: "Blue Row", thingy_request_id: nil, error: nil, two_hour_warning_sent: nil, identifier: nil, estimated_time: "", thingy_request_log: nil, for_customer_api: false, removed: false, edit_date: "2018-08-27", edit_hours: "08", edit_minutes: "00", edit_ampm: "PM">

    ];
```

UPDATE:

I stripped off data and created a new Ruby array.

```
result = []
sr.each do |r|
  record = {}
  record[:send_time] = r.send_time
  record[:ambulance_type] = r.ambulance_type
  result << {:ambulance => record}
end
result
```

I am using this now. `var taken = <%= @taken.as_json %>;`

Now getting this (scrub data for sensative info).

```
var taken = [{&quot;thingy&quot;=&gt;{&quot;send_time&quot;=&gt;&quot;2018-08-25T18:00:00.000+00:00&quot;, &quot;thingy_type&quot;=&gt;&quot;Row Delivery&quot;}}
```

Comment: You can also use `gon gem` Follow the link for more information https://github.com/gazay/gon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note the difference between `as_json` and `to_json`. `as_json` returns a hash, which then is getting stringified. `to_json` will actually create a JSON string. See this question for more details and references: [Difference between as_json and to_json method in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301957/difference-between-as-json-and-to-json-method-in-ruby/38302038)

I'd recommend updating your `ScheduledRequest` model to have an `as_json` method that effectively does what is within the `each` of your update (returning a hash representation of a single `ScheduledRequest`. Then, in your view, you can

`var taken = <%= @taken.to_json.html_safe %>`

The `to_json` will return a JSON array, and the `html_safe` will ensure it doens't get html encoded (which is what you're seeing above). Pulling the logic for how to represent individual `ScheduledRequest` objects ensures that the class is responsible for determining how to represent itself as JSON, vs. making that a view concern. Note that, as you have it, you are making your `@taken` variable accessible in javascript as `taken` via the assignment above.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, `@taken.inspect.html_safe` isn't a good way to pass your activerecord relation to JS, as you can see. It would probably make much more sense if you pass it as json:

```
var taken = <%= @taken.as_json %>
```

Keep in mind though, that this way you expose all of your record's content to the front-end, which might not be desired.

Comment: I tried this and created my own object but the encoding is not right.  var taken = [{&quot;thingy&quot;=&gt;{&quot;send_time&quot;=&gt;&quot;2018-08-25T18:00:00.000+00:00&quot;, &quot;thingy_type&quot;=&gt;&quot;Row Delivery&quot;}}  See above UPDATE.

Comment: Also once converted to JSON via .as_json how do I access that data in JS?